# Correct entity relationship diagram representation of a normalized table with a NOT NULL foreign key

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory, inheritance

### Intro

Hi everyone, this is mainly a classification/theoretical question on the topic of **inheritance** and **normalization** techniques in database design and their appropriate representation in entity relational diagrams. In a practical implementation it doesn't present a challenge as you could just set the attribute in question as **IS NOT NULL** and be done. However for a graphical representation I am a little confused on how to do it correctly.
Here is a github gist link with a interactive **mermaid** diagram representing a hypothetical scenario on a particular example: [gist](https://gist.github.com/papshmeare/dfe4b93e7c829b486f382e78e30c6318)

### Problem

The important part is in this section:
[image]
Assume we have an entity called PRODUCT which might have different types of attributes depending on the product in question(eg. Physical product/Digital product). For that reason we introduce two "subtables" whose PKs refer to a PRODUCTs FK attribute **product_type_id**. It is clear that a PRODUCT can only have a singular  **product_type_id** but because it can be either **PhysicalProduct** or **DigitalProduct** what kind of relationship do these two "subtables" have with PRODUCT? So far I deduced that it must be **one to (zero or one)** as presented in the graph. That's where the problem(perhaps non-existent) lies.
If we have two **one to (zero or one)** relationships to a mandatory **IS NOT NULL** attribute doesn't it infer a possibility of two **one to zero** relationships visually or is it something not clicking in my head here and that is how it is supposed to be in this kind of scenario?

Comment: Please put all & only what is needed to ask your question in your post & relate it specifically to your question. Please use text for what can be given via text. [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) (Also: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097))

Comment: There are many information modelling & diagramming & DB design methods. What is your reference for yours? Where & why are you 1st stuck following it, after having done what? PS Rearrangements for subtyping/inheritance is not DB normalization or denormalization. The former involves outer joins & the latter 2 involve natural join. Why do you think this has to do with normalization? PS FKs are wrongly but ubiquitously called "relationships", and "1:M" etc are cardinalities of relationships represented by projections of tables (sometimes containing FKs). PS [mre]

Comment: @philipxy, I apologize if I chose wrong format to support my question, I deemed a github gist with interactive mermaid graph a viable option but now I see that MRE would have been a better choice apparently. As for your second comment, after reading through that I think I should take on a more systematic approach to what I am researching which I luckily can achieve just by answering questions you proposed to myself, thank you for that.

Comment: Posts need to be self-contained. Also text should be used for what can be given via text. Moreover mermaid has a standard text format. (But you should give a legend for it, as you should also for an image.) It's not clear what you are trying to say or what is a problem. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. (What does "two one to zero relationships visually" mean? What's your reasoning that it's "possible"? Are you addressing a product being of neither or of more than 1 subtype?) Best to say how you are stuck following your method.

Comment: EAV is an antipattern for DB subtypes per se, it is for avoiding implementing user requests via DDL when that is merited. [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097) [More](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190296/3404097) [How to design a product table for many kinds of product where each product has many parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695752/3404097) [More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945124/3404097) [And more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5106335/3404097) [Re EAV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23950836/3404097) And subtyping<>normalizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is multiple tables which do the same thing. In you schema, both PhysicalProduct and DigitalProduct *describe* a *product*. That is a no-no for normalization.

And just think about the product. What are you selling, that can be can be either Physical or Digital. Why "either...or", why not both? For example, I can have hardcover book as well as e-book. Or mp3 and vinyl of the same song... I cannot have a digital grocery, but it would still be weird if you start describing potatoes and strawberries by two different tables (vegetables/berries).

The situations like this, are usually solved by [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) data model. The PRODUCT table is a "general" description of the product, and we have just one PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE table, which would point to the PRODUCT as many-to-one.

```
create table PRODUCT (
   id integer primary key,
);
create table PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE (
   product_id integer not null foreign key references PRODUCT(id),
   attribute_name text not null,
   attribute_value variant not null,
   primary key (product_id, attribute_name)
);
```

All the fields you put into PhysicalProduct and DigitalProduct ("weight", "dimensions", "file_size", etc) become attributes in the PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE table. If your database does not support variant datatypes, you can make several fields like "value_int", "value_string", or just one `text` field with a convertion on a client when necessary.

Comment: thank you for your answer! EAV data model, in fact, solves my root problem completely even though I phrased the question wrong. I was actually concerned about precisely that kind of scenario where you have potentially vast amount of attributes for a given entity.